# How to call methods in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am actually following a tutorial to create a custom view.But when i try to call methods it doesnot work

Here is the tutorial
http://dialogtree.com/2011/02/ios-development-a-shape-class/

So 
1)I have created a new iPhone project Test.xcodeproj

2)Include both the classes form tutorial `Shape.h` and `Shape.m`

3)Now i heve imported Shape.h to my `TestViewController`.m where i am going to display this.

i am trying to call methods in my `TestViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        Shape * shape;
    shape = [Shape alloc];

    shape = [shape setLocationWithX:10 andY:20];

    [shape addPointWithX:10 andY:10];

    [shape setColorWithR:20 andG:30 andB:40];
    [shape setAlpha:0.5];
}
```

But it does not showing anythig, why?

What i am going wrong?

Comment: If any body know the answer post here, instead of putting -ve scoring.This is why SO is created.

Comment: -1 for bad question title and bad tagging.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the correct instantiation for an object is:

```
shape = [[Shape alloc] init];
```

Then the line

```
shape = [rectangle setLocationWithX:10 andY:20];
```

overwrites the shape object just created.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the definition and implementation of the `Shape` class I see there is a `draw` method. But this `-draw` method of your `Shape` class won't call itself!

You need to call `[shape draw:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]` in the implementation of the `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method of your custom view to actually ask the shape to draw itself!

---

[EDIT]
The answer of CocoaFu is also true and is another point you need to fix in your code

Comment: Then do debug the code (breakpoints to check methods are called, etc)